# как в slick-dots, вместо точек, вставить svg картинку?

Tags: javascript

```
    JS:
    
    // slider
    
        const carousel = document.querySelector(".carousel");
        const slickPrev = '<button type="button" class="slick-prev"><svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M22 13.5C22.8284 13.5 23.5 12.8284 23.5 12C23.5 11.1716 22.8284 10.5 22 10.5L22 13.5ZM0.939341 10.9393C0.353554 11.5251 0.353554 12.4749 0.93934 13.0607L10.4853 22.6066C11.0711 23.1924 12.0208 23.1924 12.6066 22.6066C13.1924 22.0208 13.1924 21.0711 12.6066 20.4853L4.12132 12L12.6066 3.51472C13.1924 2.92893 13.1924 1.97918 12.6066 1.3934C12.0208 0.807611 11.0711 0.807611 10.4853 1.3934L0.939341 10.9393ZM22 10.5L2 10.5L2 13.5L22 13.5L22 10.5Z" fill="white"/></svg></button>';
        const slickNext = '<button type="button" class="slick-next"><svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M2 10.5C1.17157 10.5 0.5 11.1716 0.5 12C0.5 12.8284 1.17157 13.5 2 13.5L2 10.5ZM23.0607 13.0607C23.6464 12.4749 23.6464 11.5251 23.0607 10.9393L13.5147 1.3934C12.9289 0.807613 11.9792 0.807613 11.3934 1.3934C10.8076 1.97919 10.8076 2.92893 11.3934 3.51472L19.8787 12L11.3934 20.4853C10.8076 21.0711 10.8076 22.0208 11.3934 22.6066C11.9792 23.1924 12.9289 23.1924 13.5147 22.6066L23.0607 13.0607ZM2 13.5L22 13.5L22 10.5L2 10.5L2 13.5Z" fill="white"/></svg></button>';
    
        const settings = {
            speed: 1000,
            // adaptiveHeight: true,
            infinite: false,
            dots: true,
            slidesToShow: 2.99,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            centerMode: true,
            // variableWidth: true,
            prevArrow: slickPrev,
            nextArrow: slickNext,
            responsive: [
                {
                    breakpoint: 767,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 1.99,
                        dots: false
                    }
                },
                {
                    breakpoint: 575,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 1,
                        dots: false
                    }
                }
            ]
        };
    
        if (carousel) {
            $('.carousel').slick(settings);
        }



HTML:

<div class="carousel">
            <div><img src="img/slide.png" alt="slider_1"></div>
            <div><img src="img/slide.png" alt="slider_2"></div>
            <div><img src="img/slide.png" alt="slider_3"></div>
</div>





 SCSS:
        .carousel{
        position: relative;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 1240px;
        height: 625px;
        border-radius: 45px;
        background-color: #191A23;
        img{
            width: 100%;
        }
        .slick-slide{
            padding: 84px 0 64px 0;
            margin-left: 50px;
        }
        .slick-slide{
            width: 500px;
        }
        .slick-prev, .slick-next{
            position: absolute;
            top: 435px;
            right: 396px;
            border: none;
            background-color:#191A23;
            img{
                width: 20px;
            }
    
        }
        .slick-prev{
            left: 396px;
            right: auto;
        }
        .slick-dots{
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            text-align: center;
            list-style: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            padding: 124px 0 64px 0;
        }
        .slick-dots li button {
            content: url('../../icons/Vector.svg');
            font-size: 0;
            height: 14px;
            width: 14px;
            border: none;
            margin: 0 19px 0 19px;
        }
    }
```

[image: Так должны выглядеть точки (slick-dots) и при переключении слайда они должны менять цвет на зеленый]

Comment: Мне нужно , чтобы вместо точек переключения была svg-картинка

Comment: Оформите код и отредактируйте так, чтоб он мог выполняться здесь в сниппете кода (`Ctrl + M` в редакторе кода), либо конкретно опишите Вашу проблему.

Comment: Я дополнил картинкой, Так должны выглядеть точки переключения(slick-dots) и они при переключении слайды должны менять цвет на зеленый. Картинка должна быть в формате svg.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете изменить файл slick-theme.css в этом файле прописаны все стили касающиеся  слайдера Slick.

Comment: Но лучше так не делать, это стили самой библиотеки и если их редактировать, то можно потерять все стили при переходе на новую версию библиотеки. В случае со Сликом, обновлений не будет (слайдер явно умер, последнее обновление в 17м году, да и есть более хорошие варианты), тем не менее это плохая практика.

Comment: А какую библиотеку Вы посоветуете , вместо slick-slider?

Comment: @De.Minov А какую библиотеку Вы посоветуете , вместо slick-slider?

Comment: @Егор, [Swiper.js](https://swiperjs.com/), огромный функционал, без jquery.

Answer (score 0):

вот решение данной проблемы:

```
SCSS:

//other code..

    .slick-dots li button {
        padding: 0;
        font-size: 0;
        height: 14px;
        width: 14px;
        border: none;
        margin: 0 19px 0 19px;
        background: transparent;
        display: block;
        &:before{
            content: url('../../icons/Vector.svg');                                              
        }
        
    }
```